# Forecast cost Azure API

Tags: azure, api, forecast

I'm trying to get the Forecast cost of my Azure Subscription. To do this, I'm using what I found in this documentation: [Forecast - Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/forecast/usage)

But the response of this API is Usage. Then why is the name of this "Forecast"?

What do I need to do to get an *actual* forecast of my Azure?

This is what I want to get from the API:

[image: desired]

and this is what I get:

[image: actual]

This is the URL:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/X/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2019-11-01

The request body:

```
{
   "type":"Usage",
   "dataSet":{
      "granularity":"monthly",
      "aggregation":{
         "totalCost":{
            "name":"Cost",
            "function":"Sum"
         }
      },
      "sorting":[
         {
            "direction":"ascending",
            "name":"BillingMonth"
         }
      ]
   },
   "timeframe":"MonthToDate"
}
```

Edit:
When I was adding "forecast" in the end - to this URL:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXX/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/forecast?api-version=2021-10-01

I get 400 - bad request:

[image]

same at Microsoft website:

[image]

Edit 3:

[image]

[image]

Gives me this response body:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"BadRequest",
      "message":"Invalid query definition: Invalid dataset grouping: 'BillingPeriod'; valid values: 'ResourceGroup','ResourceGroupName','ResourceType','ResourceId','ResourceLocation','SubscriptionId','SubscriptionName','MeterCategory','MeterSubcategory','Meter','ServiceFamily','UnitOfMeasure','PartNumber','BillingAccountName','BillingProfileId','BillingProfileName','InvoiceSection','InvoiceSectionId','InvoiceSectionName','Product','ResourceGuid','ChargeType','ServiceName','ProductOrderId','ProductOrderName','PublisherType','ReservationId','ReservationName','Frequency','InvoiceId','PricingModel','CostAllocationRuleName','MarkupRuleName','BillingMonth','Provider','BenefitId','BenefitName','CustomerTenantId','CustomerTenantDomainName','ResellerMPNId','PartnerEarnedCreditApplied','CustomerName','PartnerName',''.\r\n\r\n (Request ID: 16022d38-1857-4be5-a8cd-1b488325aa9b)"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the *Forecast*, query the *Forecast* endpoint of the API. You're currently targeting the query endpoint, which returns costs.

Your URL should look something like this:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscr-id}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/forecast?api-version=2021-10-01`

**EDIT:**

Since a 400 is a bad request, please have a look at the specification of the request here: [Forecast - Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/forecast/usage). Clicking the green Try it button on the top right will show you how to build your request to get the correct data.

**EDIT 2:**

Please have a closer look and try some variations. Also, communicating what you're trying and what doesn't work helps.

The steps I took:

1. Go to the documentation
2. Click the green Try it button next to the first URL
3. Select a subscription (possibly optional if you have only one)
4. Fill in a valid scope like `subscriptions/{YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION-ID}`
5. Modify the request body to be a valid one (see below for example)
6. Click the green Run button and have a look at your forecast

One valid request body that works correct over here:

```
{
  type: "Usage",
  dataset: {
    "granularity": "monthly",
    "aggregation":{
      "totalCost":{
        "name":"Cost",
        "function":"Sum"
      }
    }
  },
  timeframe: "MonthToDate"
}
```

Comment: addes another edit [edit 3]

Comment: @YuvalShpitzer, please put in a bit more effort. You're only posting screenshots and (lengthy) error messages. Have a look at the error; there's an invalid dataset grouping on `BillingPeriod`. Which probably tells us there's something like a grouping property somewhere in the dataset, and it has a wrong value. My advice: start with the bare minimum and get that working. My answer should enable you to do that. Expand from there.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you meant. I used at Microsoft doc [in this URL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/forecast/usage] 
like you see in the pictures with my sub ID and the JSON you wrote, what do I need to do better?
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with MS support on this. I opened the case as the end on May 2022 and they finally got back to me on Aug 1st 2022.
They gave me a modified request body:

```
 {
   type: "Usage",
   dataset: {
     "granularity": "monthly",
     "aggregation":{
       "totalCost":{
         "name":"Cost",
         "function":"Sum"
       }
     }
   },
   timeframe: "Custom",
   "timePeriod": {
     "from": "2022-08-01",
     "to": "2022-08-31"
   }
```

and it worked.

```
$forecast = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $forecasturi -Method post -Headers $authHeader -body $body  
    
 $forecast.properties.rows
 430.2517981776787
 2022-08-01T00:00:00
 Forecast
 USD
```